# Backup the Content for "Any" Public Account in Google+

Tags: backup, google+

Since Google+ will be discontinued soon, I want to take a backup of all contents (especially posts, including attached images) from a public account which **doesn't belong to me**. I'm only interested in his/her public post that can be seen by everyone. The number of the posts is less than 200.

I have tried to use some services that can aggregate the page into RSS Feed, and then try to save the contents, but looks like there are some limitations with this approach (e.g. image resolutions, maximum number of images).

Could anyone suggest any solution or software for me? Thanks.

Solution that requires a small amount of coding is acceptable, as I have software-development background.

Answer (score 1):

Archive Team is currently performing a large-scale archive effort on Google+ profiles. You could make a request for the profile to be backed up on their official IRC channel: irc.efnet.org #googleminus
(They also have an archiving stats overview: http://tracker.archiveteam.org/googleplus/)

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have tried to ask them through IRC, even the chatroom title is welcoming the request. unfortunately no one knows who is responsible for such request.